# linq non-invocable member - cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use clientXml as a public property of my main form class so that I can use it in other events in my form but i get the error "linq non-invocable member - cannot be used like a method".

So at the top it is defined as :

```
public List<data> clientList = new List<data>();
```

...

```
var clientXml = XDocument.Load(@"ClientData.xml");

clientList(
    from d in clientXml.Descendants("Client")
    select new RegexData(
        d.Element("Bla1").Value.ToString(),
        d.Element("Bla2").Value.ToString(),
        d.Element("Bla3").Value.ToString(),
        d.Element("Bla4").Value.ToString(),
        d.Element("Bla5").Value.ToString(),
        d.Element("Bla6").Value.ToString(),
        d.Element("Bla7").Value.ToString(),
        d.Element("Bla8").Value.ToString(),
        bool.Parse(d.Element("Bla9").Value.ToString()),
        d.Element("Bla10").Value.ToString()
    )
);
```

Comment: This is not valid C#. I guess you mean `clientList = new List<data>(from...)` or `clientList.AddRange(from...)` or `clientList = (from...).ToList();`. As your code looks now, you are trying to use the _member_ `clientList` as a method `clientList()`. This does not make sense and cannot be compiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is slightly cryptic around the "non-invocable member" part. C# is trying to tell you that using `clientList`, a field denoting a `List<data>`, as if it were a *method* is not allowed.

You should write an assignment instead:

```
clientList = (
from d in clientXml.Descendants("Client")
select new RegexData(
    d.Element("Bla1").Value.ToString(),
    d.Element("Bla2").Value.ToString(),
    d.Element("Bla3").Value.ToString(),
    d.Element("Bla4").Value.ToString(),
    d.Element("Bla5").Value.ToString(),
    d.Element("Bla6").Value.ToString(),
    d.Element("Bla7").Value.ToString(),
    d.Element("Bla8").Value.ToString(),
    bool.Parse(d.Element("Bla9").Value.ToString()),
    d.Element("Bla10").Value.ToString()
).ToList();
```

and make sure that `clientList` has `List<RegexData>` data type.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the speedy response I don't know why I didn't think of that. Kinda newer to C# and really appreciate your help!